# Permission setting on DNN SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, dotnetnuke, database-permissions

I ran into problems when trying to upgrade to DNN7.1.1 yesterday. Started messing with permissions on the ISS (and file system) and now I can´t log in to DNN.

There is database contact. A DNN module outside login-area works perfectly, loads and save data to the DB. The dnndev.db.eventlog tells me there´s an InnerException in the Login.ascx.cs when I try to log in (with Host). I reckon it´s to do with writing/reading permissions for the DNN service towards the needed tables....

Do You have any suggestion for what to do?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things you could try:

- Make sure your Connection string in web.config has the Servername AND Database.  Our DBAs changed some permissions once and I did not have the Database name in there and it broke my site.
- You could try giving the DNN user DBO and SA rights on the DNN database (Just for the install only)
- Fire up SQL Profiler to see what is happening
- Review Windows Event Viewer and SQL logs

UPDATE:

- Review the user that is used in your Application Pool and make sure THAT user has read/write access to the web directory
- If this doesn't work, try giving read to these 2 users to see if it helps (if not, take it off): **IUSR** and **IIS_IUSRS** ( http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis )

These are just a few things that come to mind.